# Is there in Swift a 'for loop' where index can increase by a factor of X

Tags: swift, for-loop

I was wondering if in `swift` there is a way to manipulate the running index on a `for loop`.

Using while the program should do the following:

```
var runIndex = 1
while runIndex <= 100000000 {
    print(runIndex)
    runIndex = runIndex * 10;
}
```

In java would look as follows:

```
for (int runIndex=1; runIndex <= 100000000; runIndex = runIndex*10){
    System.out.println(runIndex);
}
```

I looked at `stride` but does not seem to be doing factor, it only does linear

```
for runIndex in stride(from: 1, to: 100000000, by: 10) {
    print(runIndex)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift analog to:

```
for (int runIndex=1; runIndex <= 100000000; runIndex = runIndex*10){
    System.out.println(runIndex);
}
```

that gives identical output to:

```
var runIndex = 1
while runIndex <= 100000000 {
    print(runIndex)
    runIndex = runIndex * 10;
}
```

is:

```
for runIndex in (sequence(first: 1) {$0 >= 100000000 ? nil : $0*10}) {
    print(runIndex)
}
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2015879-sequence and notice that the documentation actually takes your own use case, i.e. successive powers (of 2), as an example!